# Horizontally align text in header

Tags: html, css, text, header

thanks for helping me out.

I'm trying to align my text vertically and horizontally in my header. It's just stuck at the very bottom of the header.

I cannot seem to move the text from the bottom of the header at all. I have 0 padding in my body.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: I'm trying to align the text in the centre of the header, vertically and horizontally.]

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="background">
<div class="header">
<div class="menu">   
     <ul class="nav"> 
        <li id="nav-products"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/Logo sketch.png">
    </div> 
 </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    .nav {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        position: relative;

    }

    .header {
        background-color: white;
        padding-top: 100px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;


    }

    ul { /*text header*/
        list-style: none;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px dashed #f69c55;

    }

    ul li {
        outline: 0 none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 2.6em;
        margin: 0;

    }

    a {
        color: #111;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }
```

Comment: Please create an fiddle illustrating what is happening

Answer (score 0):

So I'm editing my answer to solve your case :

In your case, if you need to center vertically & horizontally an absolute positioned element, you should use a top/bottom and a left/right offset.

**Center horizontally & vertically :**

```
ul{
  position: absolute;
  /* Add top & left offset */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* Transform your element to perfectly center it */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Center horizontally :**

```
ul{
  position: absolute;
  /* Add left offset */
  left: 50%;
  /* Transform your element to perfectly center it */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Center vertically :**

```
ul{
  position: absolute;
  /* Add top offset */
  top: 50%;
  /* Transform your element to perfectly center it */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should I remove the adjustments from the ul li, and the ul? I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you use flexbox you don't need to make the ul `position: absolute;`. Then you will need to update your ul / li style depending on what you need @SubZeroFish

Comment: If I add in the ul "bottom: 50%". It places the text outside of the header. It it possible to limit it to be 50% just in the header? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you still use position absolute, you can add
`bottom: 50%; transform: translateY(50%);` : vertically center |
`left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` : horizontally center |
`left: 50%; bottom: 50%; transform: translate(50%, -50%);` vertically & horizontally center @SubZeroFish